# Simple input form for hotspot xampp

Tags: html, xampp

I am using xampp in order to run a server on my computer. I want to setup a simple hotspot with Microsoft miniport adapter, but when people type anything, it redirects them to a page where they enter the password and after that, they can connect to the internet, otherwise they only get redirected to my page.

I will ask for there first name also but I need everything to be read as text and recorded as text (no encryption) so I can easily read who is connected and when.

I intend to use this simple HTML script, but after that I have no idea what the form handler should be and how to record the information as text.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
     First name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
     Password:<br>
     <input type="text" name="password" value="Mouse"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[Link to code](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: This is where I got to:https://www.dropbox.com/s/zi1ofi3ifaguru8/index.html?dl=0

Comment: None!? Not one person knows how to record input from a form?